# I connected Apple Mail to my Gmail account and now all my emails are going to trash (which is not good)

Tags: gmail

I need Apple Mail because a web application (Pipedrive) I'm using links to Apple Mail to send emails (it doesn't link to Gmail app).  Thus I want to use Apple Mail to send email. I don't want it to store or receive email. I just need Apple Mail to link with Pipedrive.

As a solution I tried to revoke permissions via Gmail security: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 
This however resulted in my not being able to send emails via Apple Mail.
I also went into the labels tab in Gmail and unticked "All mail" for "Show in IMAP". This has not done anything:

[image: unticked "All mail" for show in IMAP]

Answer (score 1):

So, I realized there was a setting that was making all emails drop into trash on Apple Mail.  This in turn was feeding back to Gmail and causing all messages to be moved to trash.  This [article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892?hl=en) told me the correct setting to be changed in Apple Mail preferences->mail box behaviours. Specifically:

Drafts unticked,
Sent unticked,
Junk ticked,
Trash unticked.

It would be nice to know the mechanics of why this works but that's a chapter for another day.